# Pandas: Calculate average for all entries that only differ in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I just picked up `pandas`, thinking that it will enable me to do data analysis nicely in python. Now I have a `pandas` data frame of the following form:

```
pandas.DataFrame({"p1": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]*2,
                  "p2": [1]*6+[2]*6,
                  "run": [1, 2]*6,
                  "result": xrange(12)})

    p1  p2  result  run
0    1   1       0    1
1    1   1       1    2
2    2   1       2    1
3    2   1       3    2
4    3   1       4    1
5    3   1       5    2
6    1   2       6    1
7    1   2       7    2
8    2   2       8    1
9    2   2       9    2
10   3   2      10    1
11   3   2      11    2
```

I would like to generate the frame that contains one entry for every set of parameters `p1` and `p2` with the average of all values of `result` for these parameters, that is,

```
   p1  p2  result
0   1   1     0.5
1   2   1     2.5
2   3   1     4.5
3   1   2     6.5
4   2   2     8.5
5   3   2    10.5
```

What is the `pandas` way to do this? I would try to copy the original table, drop columns that differ (`result` and `run`), reindex that, combine both things again with the new index as multi-index and then run the mean method for that outer multi-index level. Is that *the* way to do it, and if yes, how do I do these index things properly in code?

Comment: It'd be handy for people to run/test this, to provide copy/pastable code that provides the DF (rather than having to process your post)

Comment: e.g. output of `df.to_dict()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use groupby (I have called your dataframe df):

```
df.groupby(['p1', 'p2']).mean()
```

This results in a MultiIndex DataFrame. To get the layout in your question, select only the columns you want and reset the index:

```
df.groupby(['p1', 'p2']).mean()['result'].reset_index()
```